# Garbage Collection of Symbols Ruby 2.2.1

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, ruby-2.2

So garbage collection of symbols has been introduced from Ruby 2.2+ version. I wrote the following the code snippet in irb :

```
before =  Symbol.all_symbols.size #=>3331
100_000.times do |i|
  "sym#{i}".to_sym
end

Symbol.all_symbols.size #=> 18835
GC.start
Symbol.all_symbols.size #=>3331
```

So as expected it collected all the symbols generated dynamically with `to_sym`.

So how does the GC know which symbols to collect? Would it collect the symbols even if they were referenced in the program? How does symbol garbage collection work? If one of the symbols I created were being referenced in the program would it still collect it?

I am using Ruby 2.2.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Basically, all symbols **created dynamically** while Ruby is running (via `to_sym`, etc.) **can be garbage** collected because they are not being used behind the scenes inside the Ruby interpreter. However, symbols created as a result of creating a new method or symbols that are **statically** inside of code **will not be garbage collected**. For example `:foo` and `def foo; end` both will not be garbage collected, however `"foo".to_sym` would be eligible for garbage collection.

See [Richard Schneeman's post](http://www.sitepoint.com/symbol-gc-ruby-2-2/) as a reference.